# Unable to extract value from the Response in Postman

Tags: postman

I want to extract id value from the following response body.

```
   [
        {
            "id": "6311ebc04318ce16bedd1a14",
            "creationMethod": "board-creation",
            "name": "workspace18669413",
            "credits": [],
            "displayName": "Prashant Vadher's workspace",
            "desc": "",
            "descData": {
                "emoji": {}
            },
            "domainName": "epam.com",
            "idBoards": [],
            "idEnterprise": null,
            "idMemberCreator": "6310461591394a03d2012ca3",
            "invited": false,
            "invitations": [],
            "limits": {
                "orgs": {
                    "totalMembersPerOrg": {
                        "status": "ok",
                        "disableAt": 4000,
                        "warnAt": 3200
                    },
                    "freeBoardsPerOrg": {
                        "status": "ok",
                        "disableAt": 10,
                        "warnAt": 3
                    }
                }
            },
            "memberships": [
                {
                    "idMember": "6310461591394a03d2012ca3",
                    "memberType": "admin",
                    "unconfirmed": false,
                    "deactivated": false,
                    "id": "6311ebc04318ce16bedd1a16"
                }
            ],
            "membersCount": 1,
            "prefs": {
                "permissionLevel": "private",
                "orgInviteRestrict": [],
                "boardInviteRestrict": "any",
                "externalMembersDisabled": false,
                "associatedDomain": null,
                "googleAppsVersion": 1,
                "boardVisibilityRestrict": {
                    "private": "org",
                    "org": "org",
                    "enterprise": "org",
                    "public": "org"
                },
                "boardDeleteRestrict": {
                    "private": "org",
                    "org": "org",
                    "enterprise": "org",
                    "public": "org"
                },
                "attachmentRestrictions": null
            },
            "powerUps": [],
            "products": [],
            "billableMemberCount": 1,
            "activeBillableMemberCount": 1,
            "billableCollaboratorCount": 0,
            "url": "https://trello.com/workspace18669413",
            "website": null,
            "logoHash": null,
            "logoUrl": null,
            "premiumFeatures": [
                "additionalBoardBackgrounds",
                "additionalStickers",
                "customBoardBackgrounds",
                "customEmoji",
                "customStickers",
                "plugins"
            ],
            "promotions": [],
            "enterpriseJoinRequest": {},
            "standardVariation": null,
            "availableLicenseCount": null,
            "maximumLicenseCount": null,
            "ixUpdate": null,
            "teamType": null,
            "canEditDomain": true
        },
        {
            "id": "6310461e34b26a003d4f65d9",
            "creationMethod": null,
            "name": "userworkspace78017157",
            "credits": [],
            "displayName": "Trello Workspace",
            "desc": "",
            "descData": {
                "emoji": {}
            },
            "domainName": "epam.com",
            "idBoards": [
                "6311d55c9640b1010ee3a9e6",
                "6311e8216b6cd7003e656e5c",
                "6311ec42e22f75004513983e",
                "6311f1b3b36e0c007e68ccbb"
            ],
            "idEnterprise": null,
            "idMemberCreator": "6310461591394a03d2012ca3",
            "invited": false,
            "invitations": [],
            "limits": {
                "orgs": {
                    "totalMembersPerOrg": {
                        "status": "ok",
                        "disableAt": 4000,
                        "warnAt": 3200
                    },
                    "freeBoardsPerOrg": {
                        "status": "warn",
                        "disableAt": 10,
                        "warnAt": 3,
                        "count": 3
                    }
                }
            },
            "memberships": [
                {
                    "idMember": "6310461591394a03d2012ca3",
                    "memberType": "admin",
                    "unconfirmed": false,
                    "deactivated": false,
                    "id": "6310461e34b26a003d4f65db"
                }
            ],
            "membersCount": 1,
            "prefs": {
                "permissionLevel": "private",
                "orgInviteRestrict": [],
                "boardInviteRestrict": "any",
                "externalMembersDisabled": false,
                "associatedDomain": null,
                "googleAppsVersion": 1,
                "boardVisibilityRestrict": {
                    "private": "org",
                    "org": "org",
                    "enterprise": "org",
                    "public": "org"
                },
                "boardDeleteRestrict": {
                    "private": "org",
                    "org": "org",
                    "enterprise": "org",
                    "public": "org"
                },
                "attachmentRestrictions": null
            },
            "powerUps": [],
            "products": [],
            "billableMemberCount": 1,
            "activeBillableMemberCount": 1,
            "billableCollaboratorCount": 0,
            "url": "https://trello.com/userworkspace78017157",
            "website": null,
            "logoHash": null,
            "logoUrl": null,
            "premiumFeatures": [
                "additionalBoardBackgrounds",
                "additionalStickers",
                "customBoardBackgrounds",
                "customEmoji",
                "customStickers",
                "plugins"
            ],
            "promotions": [],
            "enterpriseJoinRequest": {},
            "standardVariation": null,
            "availableLicenseCount": null,
            "maximumLicenseCount": null,
            "ixUpdate": "6",
            "teamType": null,
            "canEditDomain": true
        }
    ]
```

I have tried following code:

```
*jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody)
console.log("JSON Body - " + JSON.stringify(jsonData))
pm.environment.set('idOrganization', JSON.stringify(jsonData.id))
console.log("idOrganization: " + JSON.stringify(jsonData.id))*
```

But getting undefined value in console.
**idOrganization: undefined**

Is there any other way to save this value in environment variable ?

Comment: There are 2 objects with 2 ids? Which id do you want to save?

Answer (score 2):

could you try such:

```
const responseJson = pm.response.json();

pm.environment.set("idOrganization", responseJson[0]["id"]);
```

this is for the first item from your array.

Answer (score 1):

Guess your requirement is unclear, there are two `id's` present, which one you want to retrieve? If any specific it is already answered.

If you want both with comma separated, then please try this.

```
 const responseBODY = pm.response.json();
let idValue = "";
for (let i=0; i < responseBODY.length; i++) {
            idValue += responseBODY[i].id+",";
        }
finalIDValue = idValue.substring(0,idValue.length - 1); 
//put your logic how you want to use it
pm.environment.set("idOrganization", finalIDValue);
```